# ERROR "ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT" to Form Login

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, spring-security, https

Why does this error come out when authorizing the user. Did everything according to instructions.

It is  not working with HTTPS. In HTTP all normal.

everything works fine except the login form....

@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

```
@Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/accaunt/company/**").hasRole("COMPANY")
        .antMatchers("/accaunt/resume/**").hasRole("WORKER")
        .antMatchers("/accaunt/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
        /*
         *  установка второго параметра (alwaysUse) в false 
         *  говорит Spring Security что в случае успешной 
         *  авторизации можно перенаправить пользователя на 
         *  ту страничку, с которой он пришел на страницу аутентификации. 
         */
        .formLogin()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/accaunt/main", true)
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .csrf().disable()
            .requiresChannel() //config request to use the mapping to a required channel
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure();

    //maps the port 8080(http) to 8443(https)
    http.portMapper().http(8080).mapsTo(8181); 

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of my head,

1. the servlet container is not marking the request secure and setting `HttpServletRequest.getScheme` to return the correct value
2. Another filter is catching the request
  3.

You could insert a filter early in the filter chain to review specifically the `HttpServletRequest.getScheme` value when the request comes in. This is what Spring Security uses to do the evaluation.

If the web container (tomcat/jetty) are not setting the scheme properly on the HttpServletRequest then it's a container configuration issue.

I've created some samples for you to play around with
I want you to specifically pay attention to the [test](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/4e15fd9cfc89c98db0e8cb3933171c18a70f01f7/samples/requires-secure-with-redirect/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/TestRequiresSecureRedirect.java?ts=4#L115-L131) that may be happening in your case

```
git clone https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community.git
cd spring-security-community
./gradlew :spring-security-community-samples-requires-secure-with-redirect:bootRun
```

The tests in this sample show a working example and omits the reliance on the web server

A working configuration may look like:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
    http
        //application security
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/non-secure/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
            .and()
        .portMapper().http(8080).mapsTo(8081)
    ;
    // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

I've also created the [integration tests](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/490fad83b4572d7a1026ddecddb375058fd407b6/samples/requires-secure-with-redirect/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/TestRequiresSecureRedirect.java?ts=4#L46) that verify this configuration.

Comment: There are definitely scenarios where this can cause [infinite redirect loops](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/490fad83b4572d7a1026ddecddb375058fd407b6/samples/requires-secure-with-redirect/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/TestRequiresSecureRedirect.java?ts=4#L120-L122)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try later. And I will write to you. Now I need to deal with learning matters.